# Running mvn integration-test does not run robotframework test cases

Tags: java, automation, integration-testing, maven-plugin, robotframework

The documentation for robotframework:run goal says it binds to the integration-test lifecycle of maven. This should mean if I simply run mvn integration-test, my robot test cases should execute. However, this is not happening. The command mvn integration-test robotframework:run  works though.

Here is how I've declared the plugin in my POM.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>robotframework</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <testCasesDirectory>src/test/resources/robotframework/acceptance</testCasesDirectory>             
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin by default binds to the integration-test phase. That means that in your execution, if you omit the phase element, it will be integration-test by default. **You still need an execution** to get the plugin to do anything during a phase automatically. Try adding the executions part to your existing configuration, which is in the getting started example.

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
               <goals>
                   <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>robotframework</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
            <testCasesDirectory>src/test/resources/robotframework/acceptance</testCasesDirectory>             
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```